# custom no-value DOM attribute in angular

Tags: angularjs, dom, attributes

I've got an input that I either want to have custom `data-error` attribute present:

```
<input data-error>
```

or not:

```
<input>
```

Let's say I've got an boolean `error` variable available on the scope, which is to define whether to display the attribute or not. How should I do that in angular?

I tried some combinations with setting `ng-attr-data-error` but I didn't manage to get expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
<input ng-attr-data-error="{{error && 'when-error-true' || undefined }}">
```

It adds `data-error` attribute (with value `when-error-true`) when `error` is `true` otherwise it removes the data-error attribute.